# appcache, how to detect the change of the manifest file

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working on the application cache on Google Chrome.
So I created a progress bar in order to inform the user the progression.

But when the manifest file is changed, I'd like to inform the user that a new version is available.

After looking for in the web, I tried this code :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
if (window.applicationCache) {
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
  if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
      // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
      // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new hotness.
      window.applicationCache.swapCache();
      if (confirm('A new version of this App is available. Load it now?')) {
            window.location.reload();
      }
    } else {
      // no manifest change..
    }
}, false);

// if there is no update, display a message
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function(e) {

  alert('App is up to date. ');

}, false);
```

But the downloading event is always called before updateReady. This means, that all files have been downloaded and after that, I have the alert ("a new version of this app is available...")

I'd like to have the message "a new version is available" and when the user click on "yes", the downloading event has to be called

What is missing ?

My original code with progress bar :

```
        var appCache = window.applicationCache;
        appCache.addEventListener('downloading', function (e) {
            showProgressBar();
        }, false);

        appCache.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
            updateProgressBar(e.loaded, e.total);
        }, false);

        appCache.addEventListener('cached', function (e) {
            cacheSucceed();
        }, false);

        appCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (e) {
            cacheSucceed();
            appCache.swapCache();
        }, false);

        appCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function (e) {
            //cacheSucceed();
        }, false);

        appCache.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
            cacheFailed();
        }, false);

        function showProgressBar() {

            var bodyElement = angular.element("body");

            var progressBarElement = "<div id='progress-bar'><p style='color:white'>New version. Application cache in progress...<span id='progressMessage'>0%</span></p><progress id='progressBar' value='5' min='0' max='100'>0%</progress></div>";
            bodyElement.prepend(progressBarElement);

            var progressBarElement = angular.element("#progress-bar");
            progressBarElement.fadeIn("slow");
        }

        function hideProgressBar(message) {

            var appcacheStatusElement = angular.element("#appcacheStatus");
            appcacheStatusElement.text(message);

            var progressBarElement = angular.element("#progress-bar");
            progressBarElement.addClass('hidden');

        }

        function updateProgressBar(loaded, total) {
            var pourcentage = Math.round(loaded / total * 100);
            var progressBarElement = angular.element("#progressBar");
            var progressMessageElement = angular.element("#progressMessage");

            progressBarElement.attr("value", pourcentage);
            progressMessageElement.text(pourcentage + " %");

        }

        function cacheFailed() {
            hideProgressBar("error during app cache");
        }

        function cacheSucceed() {
            hideProgressBar("application is cached");
        }
```

Thanks,